# Update Statement with inner join is not evaluating each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have a **Client** table and the client can have multiple **Claims**.
Both **Clients** and **Claims** can have **Lead** dates.
I would like the **LeadDate** for the **Client** to be the smallest date of its related **Claims**.

I know that I can use an in-line subquery with **Min(LeadDate)**, but I wanted to write the query another way.

I wanted to do it with an inner join. To my surprise the results were not what I expected. It was using the first **Claim.LeadDate** that was encountered, which was not always the minimum value.

I have create a very small example which shows the result is not the minimum date. After running the query below, I would expect the **Client.LeadDate** to be **2003-01-01**.

Can someone help me understand why this is not the case?

```
begin tran

select * into #contact
from
    (values(1,convert(Date,'2007-01-01'))) as tmp(ID,LeadDate)

select * into #claim
from
    (values
        (1,1,convert(Date,'2005-01-01')),
        (2,1,convert(Date,'2003-01-01')),
        (3,1,convert(Date,'2004-01-01'))
    ) as tmp(ID,ContactID,LeadDate)

select *,case when cl.LeadDate<co.LeadDate then cl.LeadDate else co.LeadDate end Expected
from
    #contact co
    inner join #claim cl on co.ID=cl.ContactID

update co
    set
        LeadDate=case when cl.LeadDate<co.LeadDate then cl.LeadDate else co.LeadDate end 
from
    #contact co
    inner join #claim cl on co.ID=cl.ContactID

select * from #contact

rollback
```

Comment: Why would you think it would be any specific data? You have three claims for the one contact. If you changed your update to be a select you would get three rows. An update using this will use the first date in the result set.

Comment: I would think the set would be evaluated for each matching row, which would ultimately lead to the smallest value being used. I am not sure why this is not the case. Is it just picking a random row, the first row, the last row? I couldn't find documentation to guide me.

Comment: Because the behavior is undefined. Run this with and without `PRIMARY KEY` on `@t2`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6769a1f9516a907d4921fdf57b1ea8a0 If there are multiple matches and you expect a specific one to be the "winner," you need to force SQL Server's hand, or it's just going to do what's most efficient / least amount of work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That absolutely makes sense if it only evaluates a single row for the matched set. With that understanding, I can just force a sort either through query or index. I am still surprised that it only evaluates the one row. Thanks for stating that it is undefined. Now I know why I couldn't find documentation.

Comment: "Force a sort" in some indirect way still doesn't make the result deterministic. It might be "this is what I observe most of the time" but that is different. If you can identify _which row_ you want to be the one that applies, can't you do that deterministically?

Comment: Finding a solution to the problem was not my intent. My post's goal was to gain insight into how sql server was processing the query, because it was behaving in a way that I had not experienced before.

To get the correct result and to make it deterministic, I would precalc the values I wanted into a single row representing claims. I would then join that back to clients.

With that said, what would your approach be?

Comment: Ahh I think you are confused that it is only evaluating one row. It joins all the rows but then it has to decide which value to actually use for the update so it just picks the first row it finds. Hopefully the discussion has helped gain some insight on why it is behaving the way it is.

Comment: @SeanLange Would that be consider evaluating all of the rows? I agree it is joining all of the rows in each set. You are correct in that it then picks a row and uses the value for that row to evaluate the set portion of the statement. If it were evaluating and updating for each row, then it would have to end up finding the minimum value.

Comment: Why would it have to find the minimum value? That makes no sense. You don't specify it should use the minimum value. That leaves the sql engine free to pick whatever value it wants.

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994870/update-statement-with-inner-join-is-not-evaluating-each-row/69996637#comment123733432_69994870), updating a row multiple times is undefined behaviour, and normally results in SQL Server just picking one row to use for the update.

Instead you can pre-aggregate your results

```sql
update co
    set
        LeadDate = cl.LeadDate
from #contact co
inner join (
    select
      cl.ContactID,
      LeadDate = MIN(cl.LeadDate)
    from #claim cl
    group by
      cl.ContactID
) cl on co.ID = cl.ContactID;
```

You can also do this with an `APPLY`, or a correlated subquery. In some cases you may need to use row-numbering for this.

I must say, I disagree with the whole premise of this `update`. You should not be storing the same data multiple times anyway. If you want to calculate `LeadTime` then calculate it as and when you need it. Don't denormalize unless you really have to.